# MVC DropDownList item issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am quiet new with MVC. I am creating the user management module for authenticating and authorizing users withing that application. Hence, I created 2 models one for user roles and the other for user details.

I created two models like this:

```
public class RolesModels
{
    public RolesModels()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<UserModels>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Caption")]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can Create")]
    public bool createRole { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can View")]
    public bool viewRole { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can Modify")]
    public bool modifyRole { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can Delete")]
    public bool deleteRole { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserModels> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserModels
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int user_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 3 characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string user_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 4 characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string user_pass { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Registeration Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enable")]
    public bool status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Roles")]
    public virtual RolesModels Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and I have the registration controller action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult registration()
{
   // var md = from m in db.RolesModels
   // orderby m.Caption descending
   // select m;
   // Html.DropDownList("Roles", new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles), new { @id = "dropdown" });
   ViewBag.Roles = db.RolesModels.Select(r => r.Caption);
   ViewBag.RolesId = db.RolesModels.Select(r => r.RoleId);

   return View();
}
```

I created a view for the registration with a dropdownlist like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles), new { @id = "dropdown" })
```

My HTTPPost is here

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult registration(Solnet_HotelSuite.Models.UserModels user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new DBEntity()) 
            {
                var sysUser = db.UserModels.Create();
                sysUser.user_name = user.user_name;
                sysUser.user_pass = user.user_pass;
                sysUser.UserEmail = user.UserEmail;
                sysUser.RegDate = user.RegDate;
                sysUser.RoleId = user.RoleId;
                //sysUser.Roles = user.Roles;
                sysUser.status = user.status;
                db.UserModels.Add(sysUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

But whenever I clicked on Register user, I get the error :

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is Register User a button? Does your list even populate?

Comment: Yes the list get populated and "Register User" is a button. I also noticed, when I checked the html generated that the select tag has no value in the options but the text properties only.

Comment: So, you put your Get controller, but you're saying the problem lies in the Post controller...where is your post?

Comment: Oh! I just added the HTTPPost Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items you put in the viewbag are missing after the postback. Try changing the end of your HttpPost code to:

```
ViewBag.Roles = db.RolesModels.Select(r => r.Caption);
ViewBag.RolesId = db.RolesModels.Select(r => r.RoleId);

return View(user);
```

You may need to adjust this code as the `db` object may be out of scope at this point.

Comment: more clarity on this please. I got "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." after adjusting the code to suite. What do I do?